# Логика моделей в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Возник такой архитектурный вопрос. Пишу web API с применением ASP.NET MVC. ORM - Entity Framework. Правильно ли будет создавать в моделях методы для их обработки или лучше оставить в них только поля и свойства. И если правильно создавать методы, то как лучше обрабатывать ошибки/проводить валидацию/возвращать коды состояния?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Валидация

Для валидации существуют атрибуты валидации https://metanit.com/sharp/dotnet/2.2.php 
Если наследоваться от `ValidationAttribute`, то можно создать свой кастомный атрибут валидации

В моём примере находится DTO, а не модель, поэтому ничего, кроме свойств и атрибутов валидации я туда не помещаю.

```
public class UpdateProductDto
{
    [Range(1, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Id must be greater than 0")] // Атрибут
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "IsActive cannot be null")] // Атрибут
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name cannot be null")] // Атрибут
    public string Name { get; set; }//
    
    [Range(0, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Price must be greater than or equal to zero")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }//

    public string ImagePath { get; set; }//

    public string Description { get; set; }//

    [Range(1, Double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "CategoryId must be greater than 0")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set;}
}
```

Это один из способов. Ещё я знаю способ, когда в сам контроллере проводят валидацию без всяких атрибутов.

#### И напоследок. Статусы ответов формируются в контроллере, а не в модели.